# How to query Firebase data after using .push() to add data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the code for when I'm pushing the data to Firebase:

```
firebase.database().ref(`booklogs/${uid}/${book_id}`).push(page_id)

booklogs : 
{HUMjSHxVKAPfVXzOId9zCBkGOgv1:{
 book28917: {
 -KYp4FdYYODDZG1FX-Pb: 1
}
}
}
```

My problem is when I query the data, the child node of the `${book_id}` includes the push key, but I only want to get the value which is `1` and not the push key.

The code I use to query is:

```
var booklogs = db.ref(`booklogs/${uid}/${project}`); 

booklogs.once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    console.log(`pages viewed are  ${snapshot.key}: ${snapshot.val()}`);
    console.dir(snapshot.val());
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(`Error : ${error}`);
  });
```

The data returned in the console is:

```
pages viewed are  2634651: [object Object]                                                                            
{ '-KYp4FdYYODDZG1FX-Pb': 1 }
```

Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to query on?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the '1' and not the push key, try using `.set()`

```
firebase.database().ref(`booklogs/${uid}/${book_id}`).set(page_id)
```

That will get rid of the object and just give you the value that you wanted. Push automatically generates a key for every value you add, so you will always get an object back. From the Firebase docs - *"For basic write operations, you can use set() to save data to a specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path."*

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shane What I did was use .push().set(object);
The reason being if I use .set() it clears out anything that was previously a child of the node that i was setting on. So using .push().set() I was able to add another item to the  book_id/pushkey/ node.

Comment: Funny though I'm able to query the past the push key with this code in angularfire 2
`code`  ngOnInit() {
    this.af.database.list(`booklogs/${uid}/${book_id}`).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(`this book log data is : ${data[0].pageOrder}`);
        // now returns just the value 1
        console.dir(data);
      }, (error) => {console.log(`book log error: ${error}`);}
    )
  }

Comment: @Dave so you are trying to save multiple results to the `.ref(booklogs/${uid}/${book_id})` ref, then query only the actual values, and not the keys, correct?

Comment: could you snapshot.val() the entire object, then loop through each of the keys to get the values that you want?

Comment: Cheers @Shane, just saw your comment now and yep that's what I ended up doing! Cheers!